# What is the best way to run a Cloud Dataflow job using Cloud functions?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have been reading and I am aware that there are similar questions to this one. My main issue is that I cannot build a template because inside my Beam code I have operations like `datetime.now()` and as far as I know if I create a template I would obtain a fixed date during the elaboration of the template and it won't be updated every time the code runs. (Please correct me if I am wrong).

I need the pipeline to run once every day. Another idea is to try to execute bash code from my cloud function and just execute `"python -m apache_beam.examples.wordcount..."` but I am not really sure how to do that. I am trying to write the CF using Python.

Comment: Use a template, and provide the date in parameter!

Comment: Hi @Jopsiton, did you try the above suggestion?<br>